# Creating additional color for moderncv

Tags: color, moderncv

I'm trying to create an additional color for `moderncv`, but am seeing unexpected behaviour.

I've created a file called `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty`, by copying the file for the `purple` color. I've changed all references to the word purple and changed the color definitions.
The file contains the following code:

```
%% start of file `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorburgundy}[2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: burgundy]

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                color scheme definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.545098,0,0}% burgundy
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
\endinput
%% end of file `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty'.
```

However, when I choose `burgundy` as a color, the end result is `purple`!
Even though the correct file is loaded (i don't get an error, which i do get if i remove the burgundy file) and I've updated the file name database and file formats.

I have no idea why the color is wrong. In fact, I don't even understand where the purple color is coming from...even if I remove the purple color style to a thumb drive it still turns up purple, even though the color definition for purple is not defined anywhere anymore...

How can I create an additional color and why is this not working?

An example document can be generated with the code below. Note that the `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty` file must exist in the same folder as the other style files.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty

\end{document}
```

Note that `education` and the box around it are purple and not burgundy/darkred.

The error in the log file:

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncvcolorburgundy.st
y"

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvcolorburgundy',
               but the package provides `moderncvcolorpurple'.
```

Comment: Have you looked at your log if the new file is used?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; I've added an example document .

Comment: @JuriRobl; it contains an error I've added to the question, I don't know why or how to resolve this tough.

Comment: I get ! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \name
         {John}{Doe}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; it compiles fine here...do you have the latest version? I'm working with version 1.3.

Comment: The log you have edited indicates that your file has `\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorpurple}` but the one you posted does not you should check your files perhaos you hav emultiple copies. You should not really put locally modified files in the standard miktex moderncv tree it will get lost or mess up on update, just leave it in the same folder as your document.

Comment: I have `\ProvidesClass{moderncv}[2013/02/09 v1.3.0 `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; I've tried that, but I get the same error. I've also checked that the style file is indeed correct and it is. It is exactly as it is posted in the question. Its almost like the style file is determined not by the content of the file, but by other means (meta properties?). I'm not sure if thats even possible with latex though..

Comment: As David said, your log clearly shows that TeX is not loading the file above, but another file on your system also called `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty` that contains the line `\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorpurple}`, and most probably the purple color scheme definitions. Just run `kpsewhich moderncvcolorburgundy.sty` to figure out which one TeX is loading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the following MWE everything works fine for me (the new file `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty` is placed in your current directory but you can also put it in your *local* TEXMF-tree).

I have the current version of `moderncv` installed (`moderncv 2013/02/09 v1.3.0`) and I recommend an update, if you use an older one!

Your errors for `\name` and `\phone` means, that this macros are not defined (in your used document class). @Xavier said in a comment, that `\name` and `\phone` will be new commands in version 1.4.0, not yet available on CTAN. One of the benefits being that you can specify as many phone numbers as you want, a common request.

With version 1.3.0 you have to use the macros I used in my MWE.

The second error seems to be, that your color `burgundy` seems to be very near to `purple`. To check whether your burgundy file works delete the comment sign in line 
`%\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}% Testcolor` and add it in the line before. On my system now the color changes significantly ...

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{moderncvcolorburgundy.sty}
%% start of file `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorburgundy}[2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: burgundy]

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                color scheme definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.545098,0,0}% burgundy
%\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}% Testcolor
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
\endinput
%% end of file `moderncvcolorburgundy.sty'.
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}    % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}   % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black' burgundy
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty

\end{document}
```

It seems that you haved mixed different versions of `moderncv`. Just do not do this. If you want to change files of a package, do never change the files in your system TeXFM tree, copy them in your local tree or copy (if possible) it in your current directory with your current cv. A new color file can be placed in the current directory or a local TeXMF-tree.

The warning

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvcolorburguny',
               but the package provides `moderncvcolorpurple'.
```

shows you, that you have called a file `moderncvcolorburguny.sty` but the macro `\ProvidesPackage` named it `moderncvcolorpurple`. Seems that you forgot to change the name there when receiving this warning. (BTW: I never got this message with your given MWE.)

Comment: That did the trick for some reason...although I have no clue why this would work and what I tried didnt. The colors are not very similar, as the definition for purple is `\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.50,0.33,0.80}% purple`, which is quite far of in green and blue. Also, I think the problem with outdated is because of the example provided with the package. The version I'm using is up to date, but the packed example is not. Thanks for the fix though!

Comment: @Mythio I would guess that the purple version was an original and the burgundy pdf just never got made because of the fatal errors in the preamble due to the `\name` syntax.

Comment: It is weird, but I'm glad its solved. Hopefully others can use your answer when trying to define their own colors.

Comment: @Mythio A calibrated screen is actually not that expensive to get (you can get a good colorimeter for less than $200) and IMHO greatly recommended for any typography or photography lover like I am. A calibrated printer, well, that's another story... :)

Comment: @Xavier; Are you the xavier that developed the package? Cause if you are, perhaps you have an idea of WHY it behaved like it did for future reference :-)

Comment: @Mythio I am. I believe that the file you posted was not loaded when you compiled your resume (as also suggested by David and as I wrote in a comment to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537863) (from famous user `samcarter`), I successfully used the following approach to use a **custom color in `moderncv`**.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % or "banking", "classic", "oldstyle" for example. "causal is the default".

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Test Title}

%% Important code starts.
\definecolor{myCustomColor}{RGB}{255, 0, 0} % Pure red.
\colorlet{color1}{myCustomColor}
%% Important code ends.

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]