# How to use footer from cleanthesis in moderncv?

Tags: header-footer, templates, thesis, cleanthesis

I have written my thesis with the template [cleanthesis](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/). Now I want to add a CV to my thesis, and I would like to write the CV with the class modernCV. Since modernCV is a class, I need to copile it separately as a pdf document and include it in my cleanthesis template. I have adjusted the color and the font as it is explained in [Change font used by moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31534/change-font-used-by-moderncv) and [Creating additional color for moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109496/creating-additional-color-for-moderncv). However, the footer in cleanthesis looks like this

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to integrate this footer in modernCV and replace the word 'Contents' with 'Curriculum Vitae' ?

Here is the latex version of the moderncv with changed font and changed color

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{moderncvcolorburgundy.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorburgundy}[2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: burgundy]
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{cmyk}{1, .50, .10, .01}% burgundy
%\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}% Testcolor
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}   
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}        % font types and character verification
\usepackage{lmodern}    % font set: Latin Modern
\usepackage{charter}    % font set: Charter
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}
\RequirePackage{microtype}          % typographic tuning
\newcommand{\tgherosfont}{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                        % las opciones de estilo son 'casual' (por omision),'classic', 'oldstyle' y 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}                          % opciones de color 'blue' (por omision), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' y 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % si desea cambiar el ando de la columna para las fechas

% datos personales
\name{John}{Doe}



\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                     % para redactar el CV en chino usando CJK
%\maketitle

{\Huge \tgherosfont Curricula Vitae}

\vspace*{20pt}

\section{ \tgherosfont Personal}
\cvitem{Surname:}{Max}
\cvitem{Forename:}{Muster}
\cvitem{Date of birth:}{16.01.1918}
\cvitem{Birthplace:}{Berlin}
\cvitem{Citizenship:}{German}

\section{\tgherosfont Studies}
\cventry{since 2013}{Freie Universit\"at Berlin}{Promotion}{}{}{Somewhere} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Good question. Right now, with teh given amount of information, the question cannot be answered. So the question by me is: Are there any news here?